# Change isUsingStaticUrlsAllowed via observer

Tags: event-observer, magento-2.0.6

I would like to change returned value by this core function:

```
//vendor\magento\module-cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images.php 

public function isUsingStaticUrlsAllowed()
    {
        $checkResult = new \StdClass();
        $checkResult->isAllowed = false;
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'cms_wysiwyg_images_static_urls_allowed',
            ['result' => $checkResult, 'store_id' => $this->_storeId]
        );
        return $checkResult->isAllowed;
    }
```

I created my own observer:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $result  = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $result->isAllowed = true;
    }
```

But it does not work and does not make sense (?). Can I change this value via observer or i need to use plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because an observer for this event already exists that is setting the same property (`Magento\Catalog\Observer\CatalogCheckIsUsingStaticUrlsAllowedObserver`) you should instead use a plug-in because there's no reliable way to tell Magento to execute your observer after the other one executes.

Comment: By the way, you can control this setting in the backend - `Store > Configuration > Content Management > Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog`. So there's no reason to create this plugin unless you want to override the config setting.